# How can I detect when a checkbox has been selected in a WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, .net, events, webbrowser-control

In my WinForms application, I have a WebBrowser control which displays a page. When the user checks/unchecks a checkbox, I want to detect that, and have an event do some processing within my winforms app.

Any idea if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the `HtmlElement` for the checkbox, then call `AttachEventHandler("change", handler)`.